# ASP.NET WebForm Hide <div>

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

on my page I'am showing some items from database.

How can I hide some div if some value of my Item is < 0

Here's div which I want to hide when Item.quantity == 0

```
<div class="campaign__offer-buybox" >
 <a href="/DodajDoKoszyka.aspx?id_produkt=<%#:Item.id_produkt %>" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <span class="campaign__offer-buybox--button js-add-to-cart">
  <span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Kup Teraz</span>
  </span>
 </a>
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

not a lot of info in your post but here is the basic way you would do it

```
  <script>
if(item.quantity =< 0){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("campaign__offer-buybox");
x.style.display = "none"; }else{
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("campaign__offer-buybox");
x.style.display = "block"; 
 }
</script>
```

good luck